# Program run keeps failing

Tags: c++, class, constructor, binary-tree

The run for the below code fails.

This is my code:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
//#include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class stack
{
public:
    stack();        // constructor
    T pop();        // pop with type BinaryTree
    void push(T x); // push BinaryTree on top
    bool empty();   // return t/f if stack is empty
    int size();     // return size to keep track of stack

private:
    T arr[10];      // array with 10 elements
    int ele;        // keeps track of top of list
};

/******************************************************/

template<class T>
stack<T>::stack()
{
    ele = 0;
}
template<class T>
T stack<T>::pop()
{
    return arr[--ele];
}
template<class T>
void stack<T>::push(T x)
{
    arr[ele++] = x;
}
template<class T>
bool stack<T>::empty()
{
    if(ele == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
template<class T>
int stack<T>::size()
{
    return ele;
}

#endif  /* STACK_H */
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
using namespace std;
```

I need 3 constructors; for the 3rd constructor it won't process. I think it's because I'm calling another constructor from the same class.

```
template<typename T> class BinaryTree
{
public:
    // Binary Tree Things
    BinaryTree();                 // default constructor to make empty tree
    BinaryTree(T ro);             // default constructor 2 to make tree with only root
    BinaryTree(T ro, T le, T ri); // default constructor 3 to make complete binary tree
    //~BinaryTree();                // destructor for dynamics
    bool  isEmpty();              // method that returns t/f if tree is empty
    T     info();                 // method to return value in root of the tree
    void  inOrder();              // traverses nodes in a tree left, root, right
    void  preOrder();             // traverses nodes in a tree root, left, right
    void  postOrder();            // traverses nodes in a tree left, right, root

private:
    struct Tree_Node              // represents a node
    {
        T Node_Info;
        BinaryTree<T> *left;      // left pointer
        BinaryTree<T> *right;     // right pointer
    };

    Tree_Node *root;              // create root with 2 pointers from this    };

};
/***********************************************************************/

template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree()
{
}

template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(T ro)
{
    this->root->Node_Info = ro;
    this->root->left = 0;
    this->root->right = 0;
}

template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(T ro, T le, T ri)
{
    // create temps for left and right
    BinaryTree<T> *templeft = new BinaryTree(le);
    templeft->root->Node_Info = le;
    BinaryTree<T> *tempright = new BinaryTree(ri);
    tempright->root->Node_Info = ri;
    // re-assign everything
    this->root->Node_Info = ro;
    this->root->left = templeft;
    this->root->right = tempright;
}

/*template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::~BinaryTree() {
    delete root; }*/

template<typename T> bool BinaryTree<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T> T BinaryTree<T>::info()
{
}

template<typename T> void BinaryTree<T>::inOrder()
{
}

template<typename T> void BinaryTree<T>::preOrder()
{
}

template<typename T> void BinaryTree<T>::postOrder()
{
}

#endif  /* BINARYTREE_H */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>
//#include "BinaryTree.h"
//#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<BinaryTree<char> > testing;
    BinaryTree<char> testing2('d', 'd', 'd');
    testing.push(testing2);
    cout << testing.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its not error from the run screen, it just pauses, then says Run Failed.

Comment: Is this your entire program?

Comment: no but i can post entire program if you would like

Comment: There are numerous errors in this code, but the most obvious is that you never allocate space for `BinaryTree::root`. Additionally, you have significant memory management issues with the default copy constructor that `BinaryTree` provides.

Comment: Ok I allocated space for root in the default copy constructor, but I still get run failed.

Edit: Only happens when i use the 3rd constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing a binary tree by value:

```
stack<BinaryTree<char> > testing;
BinaryTree<char> testing2('d', 'd', 'd');
testing.push(testing2);
```

yet, BinaryTree doesn't **support** copying, because it will do a shallow copy (there's no Rule Of Three special members). This means, the copy will share the `root` pointer and both BinaryTree's will `delete` the same `root` (assuming you uncomment that critical code).

Here's a fix that adds the necessary special members to `BinaryTree<T>` and `BinaryTree<T>::Tree_Node`:

- (Copy) constructors + destructor for `BinaryTree<T>`

  ```
  BinaryTree(BinaryTree const& other) 
      : root(other.root? new Tree_Node(*other.root) : 0) 
  {}
  ```
- (Copy) constructors + destructor for `BinaryTree<T>::Tree_Node`

  ```
  struct Tree_Node              // represents a node
  {
      T data;
      Tree_Node *left;      // left pointer
      Tree_Node *right;     // right pointer

      Tree_Node(T data, Tree_Node* left = 0, Tree_Node* right = 0) 
          : data(data), left(left), right(right) {}

      Tree_Node(Tree_Node const& other) 
          : data(other.data),
          left (other.left? new Tree_Node(*other.left) : 0),
          right(other.right?new Tree_Node(*other.right) : 0)
      {}

      ~Tree_Node() 
      {
          delete left;
          delete right;
      }
  };
  ```

  - Note I changed `Tree_Node` around so it owns other `Tree_Node` as opposed to full BinaryTree (this change is rather gratuitous, and stems from my attempts to reduce noise before attempting to fix anything)
- Also in the category "noise-reduction" I've re-plumbed `stack<T>` on top of `std::vector<T>` just to rule out this as a source of error.

> Big DISCLAIMER: Not much of this code is actually exception safe as written, now. I'll assume that exception safety hasn't been on the menu for this course, yet. **Edit** but see comment.

See it **[Live On IdeOne](http://ideone.com/htr6iA)**:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
//#include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace std;

#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class stack
{
public:
    T pop()         { assert(!empty()); T v = _data.back(); _data.pop_back(); return v; }
    void push(T x)  { _data.push_back(x); }
    bool empty()    { return _data.empty(); }
    int size()      { return _data.size(); }

private:
    std::vector<T> _data;
};

#endif  /* STACK_H */
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class BinaryTree
{
public:
    // Binary Tree Things
    BinaryTree();                 // default constructor to make empty tree
    BinaryTree(T ro);             // default constructor 2 to make tree with only root
    BinaryTree(T ro, T le, T ri); // default constructor 3 to make complete binary tree
    ~BinaryTree();                // destructor for dynamics

    BinaryTree(BinaryTree const& other) : root(other.root? new Tree_Node(*other.root) : 0) {}

    bool  isEmpty();              // method that returns t/f if tree is empty
    T     info();                 // method to return value in root of the tree
    void  inOrder();              // traverses nodes in a tree left, root, right
    void  preOrder();             // traverses nodes in a tree root, left, right
    void  postOrder();            // traverses nodes in a tree left, right, root

private:
    struct Tree_Node              // represents a node
    {
        T data;
        Tree_Node *left;      // left pointer
        Tree_Node *right;     // right pointer

        Tree_Node(T data, Tree_Node* left = 0, Tree_Node* right = 0) 
            : left(left), right(right) {}

        Tree_Node(Tree_Node const& other) 
            : data(other.data),
            left (other.left? new Tree_Node(*other.left) : 0),
            right(other.right?new Tree_Node(*other.right) : 0)
        {}

        ~Tree_Node() 
        {
            delete left;
            delete right;
        }
    };

    Tree_Node *root;              // create root with 2 pointers from this    };
};
/***********************************************************************/

template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree() 
    : root(0)
{
}

template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(T ro) 
    : root(new Tree_Node(ro, 0, 0))
{
}

template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(T ro, T le, T ri)
    : root(new Tree_Node(ro,
            new Tree_Node (le, 0, 0),
            new Tree_Node (ri, 0, 0)))
{
}

template<typename T> BinaryTree<T>::~BinaryTree() {
    delete root; 
}

template<typename T> bool BinaryTree<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return !root;
}

template<typename T> T BinaryTree<T>::info()
{
}

template<typename T> void BinaryTree<T>::inOrder()
{
}

template<typename T> void BinaryTree<T>::preOrder()
{
}

template<typename T> void BinaryTree<T>::postOrder()
{
}

#endif  /* BINARYTREE_H */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>
//#include "BinaryTree.h"
//#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<BinaryTree<char> > testing;
    BinaryTree<char> testing2('d', 'd', 'd');
    testing.push(testing2);
    cout << testing.size();
    return 0;
}

enter code here
```

Comment: So, here's a version that implements the traversals and more exception safe. It leverages `shared_ptr` to remove a lot of manual management (so it's both a good example of modern C++ and likely not useful for your C++ course). Anyways, just in case you are curious: **[http://ideone.com/6nd6tW](http://ideone.com/6nd6tW)**

Comment: Note how this removed the need for copy constructors/destructors, at the expense of simply sharing all nodes by default. More importantly, it's technically possible to construct trees that aren't acyclic, in which case a memory leak is not prevented.